# org.bluez.MediaTransport1, member=Acquire returning org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply

Tags: dbus, bluez

While trying to call Acquire dbus api from our application , the bluez stack gets the fd, imtu, omtu successfully, and sends it over dbus using g_dbus_send_reply. But when we call dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block from our application, we are unable to get the reply,and unable to get the fd, imtu and omtu.The dbus is returning org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply.

dbus version used is 1.10.10.
Bluez version - 5.37

**Dbus error seen is** ,
method call time=1493814994.072004 sender=:1.50 -> destination=org.bluez serial=50 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_A4_70_D6_7A_74_7F/fd2; interface=org.bluez.MediaTransport1; member=Acquire

error time=1493814994.074396 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.50 **error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply reply_serial=50
   string "Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"**

**Bluetoothd error seen is**,
State changed /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_79_7E_84_2C_54/fd2: TRANSPORT_STATE_PENDING -> TRANSPORT_STATE_ACTIVE
**bluetoothd[7523]: Disconnected from D-Bus. Exiting.**

Any inputs will be of great help. Awaiting for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by applying Smack patch for bluetooth.
This patch allows kernel sockets to be used by applications.

Patches are,

0001-Smack-File-receive-for-sockets.patch

0002-smack-fix-cache-of-access-labels.patch

0003-Smack-ignore-null-signal-in-smack_task_kill.patch

0004-Smack-Assign-smack_known_web-label-for-kernel-thread.patch

Gerrit link - 
https://gerrit.automotivelinux.org/gerrit/#/c/6995/